# Python ElementTreeのfindall()で取得したリストが意図しない挙動になる。

Tags: python, python3

特定のディレクトリ内のすべてのファイル情報をElementTreeでXMLに蓄積し、差分をチェックするスクリプトを作成しています。
XMLは以下のようなフォーマットです。

```
<root>
    <record author="pcname" time="2021-11-27">
        <file file_name="a.txt" md5="148991">
        <file file_name="b.txt" md5="148992">
        <file file_name="c.txt" md5="148993">
    </record>
    <record author="pcname" time="2021-11-28">
        <file file_name="a.txt" md5="148991">
        <file file_name="b.txt" md5="148992">
        <file file_name="c.txt" md5="148993">
        <file file_name="new.txt" md5="148993">
    </record>
</root>
```

最新のRecordと一つ前のRecordタグの差分をとるために以下のコードを書きました。
(HistoryXmlは私が新しく定義したクラス名です。)

```
@staticmethod
def __existSameFileName(files:list[Element],name_value:str ) -> bool:
    for file in files:
        if(file.get('file_name') == name_value):
            return True
    return False

@staticmethod
def __diffDeleted(prev_files:list[Element], last_files:list[Element]):
    for prev_file in prev_files:
        prev_file_name = prev_file.get('file_name')
        if not (HistoryXml.__existSameFileName(last_files, prev_file_name)):
            # deleted file found
            print('deleted:' + prev_file_name)

@staticmethod
def __diffNew(prev_files:list[Element], last_files:list[Element]):
    for last_file in last_files:
        file_name = last_file.get('file_name')
        if not (HistoryXml.__existSameFileName(prev_files, file_name)):
            # new file found
            print('new:' + file_name)

def diffLast(self):
    record_list = self.__root.findall('record')
    prev_record = record_list[-2] # 1つ前データ
    last_record = record_list[-1] # 最新のデータ
    prev_files = prev_record.findall('file')
    last_files = last_record.findall('file')
    HistoryXml.__diffNew(prev_files=prev_files,last_files=last_files)
    HistoryXml.__diffDeleted(prev_files=prev_files,last_files=last_files)
```

上記のXMLの期待値は"new:new.txt"のみの出力ですが、実際には"new:new.txt"と"deleted:new.txt"どちらも出力されてしまいます。

そこで私は以下のコードを書いてテストしましたが、期待通り'newfile found in prev!'が出力します。

```
def diffLast(self):
    record_list = self.__root.findall('record')
    prev_record = record_list[-2]
    last_record = record_list[-1]
    prev_files = prev_record.findall('file')
    last_files = last_record.findall('file')
    if(HistoryXml.__existSameFileName(prev_files ,'new.txt')):
        print('newfile found in prev!')
    
    if(HistoryXml.__existSameFileName(last_files ,'new.txt')):
        print('newfile found in last!')
```

Answer (score 0):

全て `staticmethod` なので関数に置き換えて実行してみました(内容は変更していません)。期待通りの結果ですね(`new:new.txt` のみ出力)。

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def existSameFileName(files, name_value):
    for file in files:
        if(file.get('file_name') == name_value):
            return True
    return False

def diffDeleted(prev_files, last_files):
    for prev_file in prev_files:
        prev_file_name = prev_file.get('file_name')
        if not (existSameFileName(last_files, prev_file_name)):
            # deleted file found
            print('deleted:' + prev_file_name)

def diffNew(prev_files, last_files):
    for last_file in last_files:
        file_name = last_file.get('file_name')
        if not (existSameFileName(prev_files, file_name)):
            # new file found
            print('new:' + file_name)

def diffLast(root):
    record_list = root.findall('record')
    prev_record = record_list[-2] # 1つ前データ
    last_record = record_list[-1] # 最新のデータ
    prev_files = prev_record.findall('file')
    last_files = last_record.findall('file')
    diffNew(prev_files=prev_files,last_files=last_files)
    diffDeleted(prev_files=prev_files,last_files=last_files)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    xml_text = '''
<root>
    <record author="pcname" time="2021-11-27">
        <file file_name="a.txt" md5="148991"/>
        <file file_name="b.txt" md5="148992"/>
        <file file_name="c.txt" md5="148993"/>
    </record>
    <record author="pcname" time="2021-11-28">
        <file file_name="a.txt" md5="148991"/>
        <file file_name="b.txt" md5="148992"/>
        <file file_name="c.txt" md5="148993"/>
        <file file_name="new.txt" md5="148993"/>
    </record>
</root>
'''.strip()

    root = ET.fromstring(xml_text)
    diffLast(root)
```

**実行結果**

```
new:new.txt
```

Comment: コメントで返信いただいたソースコードを実行したところ、期待通りの動作を確認しました。しかし、問題が発生したときのXMLファイルをいただいたソースコードで実行させたときに同じ現象が発生しました。
XML側の問題だったようです。
しかし、`record`タグを3つ目の試行からコードは正常に動作するようになりました。